# Change pixel size of multiple images!

Tags: macos, mac, images, adobe-photoshop, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program to automate image resize](https://superuser.com/questions/30801/program-to-automate-image-resize)

Hello I have a folder with 100 images and I want to change their pixel size is there an easy way to do it simultaneously to all of them, instead of picking them one by one?Thanks in advance!
My operating system is Mac OS

Comment: Change pixel size? Do you mean 'change resolution' (resize- change amount of pixels), or 'change dpi' (more accurately ppi)? You cannot change the pixel size, as a pixel is a pixel. You need to change monitors to change the size of a pixel.

Comment: Related  [Program to automate image resize](http://superuser.com/questions/30801/program-to-automate-image-resize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it can be done really easy with preview...You just open as many pictures as you like then you go to Tools->Adjust Size you choose dimensions in pixels (or whatever)and click OK!
so simple...thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 3):

Use [ImageMagick's `convert` tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/):

```
convert files*.png -set filename:area "%wx%h" -resize 50% "resized/-%[filename:area]small.png"
```

Comment: seems like a good option thanks!can you give an example for converting images to specific width and height (lets say 1024 768)?Also the concept is to be able to convert multiple images at once...is that what is happening in the example?

Comment: @rabidmachine9: Here is an example from the page I linked to: `convert dragon.gif -resize 64x64  resize_dragon.gif`. Instead of a percentage, you just use the desired dimensions. This preserves the aspect ratio. You can override that though by adding an escaped exclamation point (`64x64\!`) and it will stretch or compress the aspect ratio.

Comment: In my example, multiple files are selected using file globbing (files*.png) and a renaming operation is done using the `-set` operator and the filespec in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Photoshop, you can record your own Actions then run them with Batch processing across the Folder. I found good directions here:
http://www.geekinspired.com/graphic-design/photoshop/edit-multiple-pictures-with-photoshop-batch-and-droplet/

You also can resize a folder of images using Photoshop if they are in the JPEG, TIFF or PSD format. This is also only useful if all the images have the same dimensions like from a camera.

1. Select File > Scripts > Image Processor...
2. In the Image Processor dialog box, step 1, press the Select Folder... button and select the folder with the images.
3. In step 2, select the location where the processed images will go.
4. Select the file type and the Resize to Fit box giving the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

IF you want easy get microsoft's power tool: microsoft image resizer http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx

Select
Right-Click
Resize.

Comment: The OP is using OS X.

Answer (score 0):

- [ImageWell](http://www.xtralean.com/IWOverview.html)

[image]

- [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/)
- As a cool trick you can re-size using the preview and the automator

The below is an extract from a site , the site is mentioned below

> Say you want to resize an image (or
> lots of images) to half its size. To
> do this, drag the Scale Images action
> over to the right hand side. A dialog
> box will appear asking if you want the
> workflow to keep a copy of the
> original image or not. If you click
> Add, the workflow will make a copy of
> your image on the Desktop and resize
> that instead of the original.
> Otherwise, it will simply replace the
> image with its resized version.
>
> The next step is to choose how you
> want to scale your image. You can set
> it to a certain width or a percentage
> of its original size. Once you have
> chosen, choose Save As from the File
> menu and give it a name like Resize
> Images. From the File Format pop-up
> menu choose Application. The Desktop
> is a good place to save it.
>
> Find an image file and drag it onto
> the Resize Images icon. A copy of the
> image at half the size should appear
> on the Desktop

Have a look here http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/access-extra-preview-features-through-automator.html#unique-entry-id-148

Comment: Both are Windows tools.

Comment: Updated my answer